# PHPMail sending attachment but they are empty

Tags: php

Basically, I am trying to send a PDF via PHPMail.
the email is sent and I receive it in outlook perfectly. the problem is that the attachment is broken and it doesnt open. I even tried sending a HTML and is also empty.

I tried researching in the forum, tried several "working codes" and other people got it working with this code... I have no clue why is not working for me.
I am using the lastest version of PHPMail 5.2.2

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $staffEmail = "staffemail";
        $mail->From = $staffEmail;
        $mail->FromName = "name";
        $mail->AddAddress('my@email.com');
        $mail->AddReplyTo($staffEmail, "name");

        $mail->AddAttachment('test.pdf');
        $mail->Subject = "PDF file attachment";

        $mail->Body = "message!";
        $mail->Send();
```

Comment: Where is the attachment in relation to this script?

Comment: +1 for using a decent class to send email from php rather than the `mail()` function.

Comment: You mention that you're using the latest version of phpMailer. Can you confirm the version number you have, because some download sites are known not to be up-to-date.

Comment: they are both in the same directory. I though about that one too... thinking that maybe PHPMail works with its root path set as where the library is... but if i change the path of my PDF it doesnt insert it... so it recognised where the PDF or HTML file is... it is just sending it broken

Comment: Best not to ask the same question multiple times, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This custom PHP function will show the (beginning) PHP developer how-to build an e-mail script with attachment function. Please note that inside the mail function is no validation functionality available.

```
<?php
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = $path.$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }
}
?>
```

Next we show an example on how-to use this function to send an e-mail message with one attached zip file:

```
<?php    $my_file = "somefile.zip";
    $my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/your_path_here/";
    $my_name = "Olaf Lederer";
    $my_mail = "my@mail.com";
    $my_replyto = "my_reply_to@mail.net";
    $my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
    $my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo you like this script? I hope it will help.\r\n\r\ngr. Olaf";
    mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, "recipient@mail.org", $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
?>
```

Are you looking for a script to send multiple attachments? Try our mail attachment class script.

If you like to send your websites mail messages via SMTP and Gmail, check our PHPMailer tutorial, too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to upload the file to the server and then attach it to the email. For example, you can use the following steps :

1. Upload the file
2. Attach it to the email
3. Send the email
4. Delete this temporary file from the server

Try this because I think thats the reason of your poblem.

Just in case: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this function which uses simple mail function of PHP:

```
function mail_attachment ($from , $to, $subject, $message, $attachment){
$fileatt = $attachment; // Path to the file                  
$fileatt_type = 'application/octet-stream'; // File Type 
$start= strrpos($attachment, '/') == -1 ? strrpos($attachment, '//') : strrpos($attachment, '/')+1;
$fileatt_name = substr($attachment, $start, strlen($attachment)); // Filename that will be used for the file as the     attachment 

$email_from = $from; // Who the email is from 
$email_subject =  $subject; // The Subject of the email 
$email_txt = $message; // Message that the email has in it 

$email_to = $to; // Who the email is to

$headers = "From: ".$email_from;

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb'); 
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt)); 
fclose($file); 
$msg_txt=""; //\n\nMail created from websiteaddress systems : http://websiteaddress.com

$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

$headers .= "\nwebsiteaddress-Version: 1.0\n" . 
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
        " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

$email_txt .= $msg_txt;

$email_message = "This is a multi-part message in websiteaddress format.\n\n" . 
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
            "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".$email_txt. "\n\n"; 
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
              "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" . 
              " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
              //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
              //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
             $data . "\n\n" . 
              "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; 


$ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

if($ok) { 
//echo "Attachment has been mailed !";
//header("Location: index.php");
} else { 
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!"); 
} 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two problems either path is not correct for attachment or php dont have permission on that folder

Answer (score 0):

this one is working for me trying to send a resume has attachmnet in zend

```
            $mail = new Zend_Mail ();
            $mail->setBodyHTML ( stripslashes ($message) );

            // add attachment
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($attachemnet);
            $resume = $mail->createAttachment($fileContents);
            $resume->filename = $EmployeeDeatils['resume'];

            //$mail->createAttachment($attachemnet);
            $mail->setFrom ( $mail_template ['from_email'], $mail_template ['from_caption'] );
            $mail->addTo ( $clientemail, $employee_name );
            $mail->setSubject ($subject );
            try {
                $mail->send ();
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $this->_helper->errorlog ( " Send mail to member with activation link : " . $e->getMessage () );
            }
```