# PHP mail sends attachments successfully, but the message is empty

Tags: php, email, message, attachment

This is a part of a simple mail sending script from PHP. It does create a PDF attachment from FPDF (code is not included here) + it adds some more user uploaded attachments.

If I remove `$message` from `$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers );`, it sends the attachments just fine, but if put the `$message` back in `$mail_sent`, it seems to get mixed up with the attachments and it leaves a large chunk of text in the mail. I guess it has something to do with MIME boundaries, but I just can't figure out where the problem lies.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<?php

$to = "to@mail.com";
$from = $_POST["from@mail.com"];
$subject = "Subject"; 
$message = "This is the message";

$eol = PHP_EOL;
$filename = "$filename.pdf";

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
$fileatt_name = isset($_POST['fileatt_name']) ? $_POST['fileatt_name'] : '';

// Header
$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
$headers = "From: $from\r".$eol .
$headers = "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r".$eol .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r".$eol .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r".$eol .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.".$eol.$eol .
"--{$mime_boundary}".$eol .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol . 
"".$eol.$eol;

// PDF-Attachment
$body .= "--{$mime_boundary}".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body.="--{$mime_boundary}--".$eol;

// More attachments
 foreach($_FILES as $userfile)
         {
            $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
            $type = $userfile['type'];
            $name = $userfile['name'];
            $size = $userfile['size'];
            if (file_exists($tmp_name))
            {
               if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
               {
                  $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
                  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
                  fclose($file);
                  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
               }
               $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}".$eol .
                  "Content-Type: {$type};".$eol .
                  " name=\"{$name}\"".$eol .
                  "Content-Disposition: attachment;".$eol .
                  " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"".$eol .
                  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol.$eol .
               $data . "".$eol.$eol;
            }

         }

// Send 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $body, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "Success" : "Failed"; 

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072482/phpmail-sending-attachment-but-they-are-empty

Comment: Similar, but attachment(s) aren't broken, only the message part.

Comment: don't build your own mime messages. use phpmailer or swiftmailer, which will reduce all of that mime junk down to a single `->AddAttachment()`-type call, and then you can get on with more important things.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php not 5 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding `$body .= $message.$eol;` before the PDF-attachment.